# Text is getting cut off in VML CTA on Outlook 2013 120DPI

Tags: html-email

I am using VML to make my bulletproof CTAs work in Outlook, they seem to be working fine everywhere except on Outlook 2013 120DPI where the text is cut off in the CTA:
[image]

Everywhere else it works fine:

[image]

Here is the VML:

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://epredia.com/" style="height:34px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:176px;" arcsize="33.5px" strokecolor="#E5E5E6" fillcolor="#E5E5E6">
    <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#58595B;font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;font-size:18px;line-height:18px;">
            <b style='font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;'>
                Mini CTA
                                                    
            </b>
        /center>
    </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the scaling.

Have your HTML tag something like this (you might have different language or other attributes):

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

And in your `<head>` add this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
```

Comment: I've the same problem as OP. Though I created template in mjml which add your proposed markup appropriately but still facing issue in Outlook 2013 though it works fine in Outlook 2007 (yeah it worked). let me know if you can help. thanks

Comment: hmm maybe it's because you set the height? Play around with height, line-height and maybe even use pt for the VML instead of px. I'd first remove the height reference. Line-height would normally take care of it